# What specific properties of CFGs & CSGs do we lose, when we redefine the starting symbol to be either terminal or non-terminal?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar, formal-grammar

Both CFG(Context-Free Grammar) & CSG(Context-Sensitive Grammar) are defined as a 4-tuple $(V,\Sigma,R,S)$, with $S\in V$.

That is, in both cases $S$(the starting symbol) is a non-terminal symbol, why is that the case?
What properties do we lose going from $S\in V$ to $S\in V\cup\Sigma$?

e.g, is there a property that doesn't extend to $(,\{a\},,a)$?

Comment: If $S$ were terminal, it would be the only word in the language.

Comment: Yes, but so do grammars of the form $(\{S\},\{a\},\{S\to a\},S)$.
In essence, what I'm asking is "does there exist a theorem of CFGs that relies on $S$ being non-terminal, or on $R$ not being the empty set?"

Comment: I doubt it.  I think it's just that you don't get any interesting languages if $S$ is a terminal.